# python Discret derivation of data (x,y) x=values y=time from excel

Tags: python, excel, plot, derivative

Implement a code in the language of your choice that automatically performs the primer, second and third discrete derivative of a signal provided by means of a two-column excel file, The first will contain the time and the second the magnitude. And display the original and derived graphs.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| .1 | 1 |
| .4 | -3 |
| 1.2 | 8 |

In excel column:
A = time
B = values

Comment: it would help if you would provide sample data

Comment: What have you tried?  The "discrete derivative" is just the difference between two point values.  And you need at least 4 values to compute a third derivative.  The first derivative would be -4 and +11.  The second derivative would be 7.